# How can I simplify this jQuery caption based alert code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, parent

I am having problems making my jQuery code more efficient for a complex application I am writing. **Is there a way to make this code work better?** The multiple `parent()` functions can't, surely, be the best option!

This is my jQuery code (outside of the document ready code):

```
$(".icon .remove a").click(function (m) {
    m.preventDefault();
    var caption = $(this).parent().parent().children("a").children(".caption").contents().text();
    confirm("Are you sure you want to delete "+caption+"?");
});
```

And this is the HTML in question:

```
<div class="icon">
    <span class="config"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i></a></span>
    <span class="remove"><a href="#"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></a></span>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="image"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3653636892/753cd0095b234e216b1ffc50911a0203_bigger.png" alt="ProbabilityWolf"></span>
        <span class="caption">ProbabilityWolf</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I assume there must be a way to simplify getting the caption! The bit here called "icon" is repeated many times and always has a different caption, but always has the same structure.

Comment: use `$(this).closest('div.icon').find('.caption').text();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with a selector to find the element.

```
var caption = $(this).closest(".icon").find("a .caption").text();
```

Comment: Well, that seems to work. `$(this).closest(".icon").find(".caption").text()`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Wow, I added this comment simultaneously XD